# How to decrease gigabit ethernet network latency in Linux?

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, latency

I have a cluster with Gigabit ethernet network. I don't need more bandwidth but the latency is important. `ping` shows that the latency between nodes are about 100 microseconds. Is there a way to have lower latency with this hardware?

Comment: Is the cluster in the same physical place?

Comment: I think you mean milliseconds? If yes, then it is quite slow. If you really mean microseconds, I don't see any problem.

Comment: @NIZ: Yes. All the server, nodes and consoles are within 10 meters. So cables are not long.

Comment: @TJJ: 100 microseconds is good for usual networks, but is so bad for HPC clusters which should be in the order of 10 microseconds

Comment: Are you sure? In my network I typically reach average 1000 microseconds between nodes. So I would consider 100 microseconds on usual network exceptionally good already.

Comment: I think @TJJ is right :) Sorry missed the "microseconds" part

Comment: @TJJ : 0.1 milisecond=100 microsecond is typical for **gigabit ethernet** networks and if you have 1000 microseconds latency in gigabit, your network is so slow!!! but as I said, HPCs should have less latency. 10GB ethernet has about 1 microsecond latency, but it needs hardware upgrade and is expensive!

Comment: @mohammadh montazeri Ok. I just wanted to be sure you haven't made a mistake. Actually, I was also partly wrong because I gave my ping time as PC-to-PC, not node-to-node. So the switch will of course increase the time. So I guess yes, with expensive super fast networking technology you should be able to get lower latencies :)